# What's the difference between S3:// protocol and client method of SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, protocols, remote-access, url-scheme

I'm new to AWS S3, and I'm studying S3 SDK now.

If I would like to put a file on S3, there are two ways:

1) Using SDK client, $s3->putObject method

2) Using s3:// protocol

What's the difference between two?

Thank you! :)

Comment: Could you please provide an example of what you mean for #2? Are you referring to accessing objects in a web browser?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I'm sorry for confusing you, I've just started learning about S3 now. Via S3:// protocol, is it only available to access objects in a web browser? I would like to know the principle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accessing AWS services via an SDK will make fully-authenticated API calls. Such calls require IAM credentials. They are the best way to interact with AWS services. Some commands, such as creating buckets, are only available via API calls.

Amazon S3 has the additional ability to provide access to objects via normal HTTP/HTTPS requests. For example, if an object is **public**, it can be accessed via `https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket-name/path/object`

This means that content from Amazon S3 can be incorporated into web pages via `<a>` and `<img>` tags.

If you wish to use such links to access **private** objects, then the URL will need additional authentication information attached. This is know an a [Amazon S3 pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html).

Comment: Thank you so much! Can you explain about s3:// protocol? REF: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/s3-stream-wrapper.html I would like to know what is it starting S3:// for example, file_put_contents('s3://bucket/key', 'Hello!'); and the difference between SDK way putObejct

Comment: That looks to be PHP-specific. Sorry, I'm not familiar with the PHP SDK.

Comment: Oh I see. I was curious about stream wrapper. Thank you so much for your help. I appreciate it!